# Why isn't beautiful soup showing the first block of HTML code from a page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm using VirtualStudio code and when I print page_soup I get a whole bunch of html code, but it seems to be missing the beginning lines including the first "doctype html" statement.

```
   import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#For sites that can't be opened due to Urllib blocker, use a Mozilla User agent to get access
pageRequest = Request('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
htmlPage = urlopen(pageRequest).read()


page_soup = soup(htmlPage, 'html.parser')
print(page_soup)
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the HTML? Have you tried writing it to a file and checking there?

Comment: I dont know how to write to a file but I copied and pasted the entirety of my output and viewed it in sublime text, and it did not contain the expected few lines of code such as doctype, lang, etc. Here are the first few lines of the output.                             <th scope="col">908</th>
<th scope="col">916</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Daily Cases</th>
<th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell" scope="col">11</th>

Comment: Depending on where you're printing this html, it may just be interpreted and rendered accordingly. That would explain the missing code.

Another possibility is that what you are seeing in e.g. Chrome isn't the same code as you're getting with urllib, because browsers like to make changes to HTML to "fix" it. Happens regularly to me when building xpath locators...

Comment: I'm not sure why the print statement in VSCode would make any alterations, how can I go about getting the correct html code in its entirety? Would this affect my scraping if I leave it be?

Comment: @Josh _I dont know how to write to a file but I copied and pasted the entirety of my output..._ The reason I asked about writing to a file is to ensure that the output isn’t just getting cut off somehow when displayed. Writing to a file (use the output of `page_soup.prettify()`) in Python is dead simple, there are plenty of resources on the subject.